# How to call the overloaded version of operator()

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    void operator()(char c){ std::cout << c << std::endl; };
    void operator()(const char * p)
    {
        while( *p != '\0' )
        {
             this( *p++ );  # error: expression cannot be used as a function
        }
    }
} s ;

int main()
{
    s( "blqhblqh" );
}
```

How to call the overloaded version?

Comment: `(*this)(*p++)` or `this->operator()(*p++)` or `operator()(*p++)`. `decltype(this)` is `struct S*` not `struct S`.

Answer (score 2):

`operator()` is supposed to be called on the instance of `S`, but not a pointer to `S` like `this`. So

```
(*this)( *p++ );
```

Or more ugly to call the `operator()` directly.

```
this->operator()( *p++ );
(*this).operator()( *p++ );
```

Comment: OMG, such a silly mistake. Thank you for your time!